# WCF Service populate data to ASP.net dropdownlist (Learning WCF Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, dropdown

I am attempting to learn the WCF Service to incorporate eventually incorporate with one of our websites.

I have created a test table in my database called, [TestTable]
I have been able to successfully write data to the table from a test site created in visual studios.

I am now attempting to populate a dropdownlist from the database. In this case, a list of all states.

There appears to be something I am missing.  I can invoke the service and it will show all states in the WCF Test Client; however, I cannot seem to figure out how to attach the list it returns to the ASP.net dropdown list.

Here is my IService1.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    //string GetData(int value);
    string InsertApplicantDetails(ApplicantDetails appInfo);

    [OperationContract]
    List<US_States> GetAllStates();

    //CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here

}
```

Here is my Service1.svc.cs for GetAllStates

```
public List<US_States> GetAllStates()
    {
        using (JobSeekersEntities db = new JobSeekersEntities())
        {
            var q = (from us_states in db.US_States
                     orderby us_states.abbr ascending
                     select us_states);

            List<US_States> list_States = q.ToList<US_States>();

            return list_States.ToList();

        }
    }
```

In the test website I have created the dropdownlist called, "dropdownStates".
I have added the ServiceReference and it is working as I can submit values to the database.
I have also created a Load() event for the dropdownlist.

Here is my Test page.

```
public partial class TestSubmission : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client objCon = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void dropdownStates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ServiceReference1.Service1Client myCon = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    dropdownStates.Items = ????

}
```

}

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have defined proper DataContract and Service Contract.
In following sample I have defined US States with 2 properties.
Pay attention to [OperationContract] and [DataContract] declarations!

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        List<US_States> GetAllStates();

    }


    [DataContract]
    public class US_States
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int StateId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next add WebService reference to your project amd make a call like this:
(Binding StateName to Text and StateId to Value)

```
    protected void dropdownStates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        dropdownStates.Items.Clear();
        dropdownStates.DataSource = client.GetAllStates();
        dropdownStates.DataTextField = "StateName";
        dropdownStates.DataValueField = "StateId";
        dropdownStates.DataBind();
        client.Close();
    }
```

And finally the Service:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public List<US_States> GetAllStates()
        {
            List<US_States> result = new List<US_States>();
            result.Add(new US_States() { StateId = 1, StateName = "New York" });
            result.Add(new US_States() { StateId = 2, StateName = "Washington" });
            result.Add(new US_States() { StateId = 3, StateName = "Indiana" });
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance.  This got me up and running. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
        dropdownStates.Items.Clear();
        dropdownStates.DataSource = client.GetAllStates();
        dropdownStates.DataTextField = "Name";
        dropdownStates.DataValueField = "Id";
        dropdownStates.DataBind();
}
```

You just need to set Dropdown DataSource to the list. set text and datavale field accoridng to what you want to display as item and what value it shuld have and finally call DataBind.